# Incrase memory ussage of apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a server with 8GB RAM. My problem is that the server load is too high and apache is very slow, but it use only 800MB of RAMm. How it works? Can I give to one webpage on my server 7GB ram or 6GB ram to use it?

I think 800MB used memory from 8GB and high server load is not good.

Load average: 1.66, 1.73, 2.12 Uptime: 173 days, Tasks 711, running: 2

Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D525 @ 1.80GHz (4 CPU), 4gb Swp, Debian server with i-mscp controll panel.

**htop says /usr/sbin/mysqld.... uses 98% of CPU**.
 I have got 2 HDD, 250GB for the linux and 2TB for /var/www/webpages....

844MB RAM used from 8GB, 308MB Swp used from 4GB.

2GB/s net connection.

Mysql database size: 153Mb,

There are about 5 cronjobs in every 5 minutes.

Sometimes my website gives me server error, cos lack of resoures, but the other sites are online with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. What's hogging your CPU is MySQL, not Apache. If it thinks it can benefit from using more RAM, it will. Obviously, that's not the case.
2. You need to check why it uses so much CPU time. Maybe you can optimize the database queries of your application, but that's not guaranteed, as they just might *need* all that power because of what they do.
3. If you are CPU-constrained, using more RAM doesn't help. What on earth makes you think it would?
4. If you indeed have 4 cores, having a load of 2.1 means that only half of your cores get used, so your system is definitely not overloaded.
5. If you have CPU-intensive tasks, using a tiny little toy CPU like an Atom is nonsense.
6. If your Apache is "slow", it's likely a result of having to wait for MySQL.